# Can somebody explain me this Binary tree transplant algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I found this algorithm in a textbook and I'm not sure I understand it.

```
TRANSPLANT(T,u,v){
  1 if u.p == NIL
  2   T.root = v
  3 else if u == u.p.left
  4   u.p.left=v
  5 else u.p.right == v
  6 if v != NIL
  7   v.p=u.p
}
```

Also, what do you think is `p` inside the node?

Why can't he just compare the node with the node?

Notes from textbook:

> In order to move subtrees around within the binary search tree, we define a
>   subroutine `TRANSPLANT`, which replaces one subtree as a child of its parent with
>   another subtree. When `TRANSPLANT` replaces the subtree rooted at node `u` with
>   the subtree rooted at node , node `u`'s parent becomes node ’s parent, and `u`'s
>   parent ends up having  as its appropriate child.

Comment: The ```p``` in this code stands for the “parent” as -> ```u.p // means ref to u’s parent```.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I understood the code, it tries to replace the node u and its corresponding subtree with some other node v and its subtree. I assume that p stands for the parent of a node.

```
TRANSPLANT(T,u,v) {
1   if u.p == NIL          -- if u doesn't have a parent => u is the root
2       T.root = v         --   then v must replace u as the root of the tree T
3   else if u == u.p.left  -- if u is a left subtree of its parent
4       u.p.left = v       --   then v must replace u as the left  
-                          --   subtree of u's parent
5   else u.p.right == v    -- otherwise u is a right subtree 
-                          --   (as the tree is binary) and v must replace
-                          --   u as the right subtree of u's parent
6   if v != NIL            -- if v has replaced u (and thus is not NIL)
7       v.p = u.p          --   v must have the same parent as u
8 }
```